# output void function to txt

Tags: c++, iostream

I am only in my second quarter of c++ so please keep answers simple....

I have a pretty messy program with linklist, class, and file i/o
I am pretty much done with the program but I cant get it to output to a .txt
It might have been my bad coding layout, since outputting slipped my mind when I wrote this.
the function in question is:

```
tag.display_balance();
```

note that this function is inside a linklist (tag) that goes into a class and call the function (display_balance) to print the outputs.

everything comes out to the console just fine. but I dont know how to get it save onto a .txt
a few Google and forum searches didnt show anything that I can understand.
I tried:

```
ofstream BilloutPut;
BilloutPut.open("BillingStatements.txt");
BilloutPut<< tag.display_balance();
```

which is the only way I have learned how to output to a file, but since it is a void function it  didnt work.  I would like to keep away from overloading the << function if possible.

-Thanks for looking

Comment: Are you using `cout` in `display_balance`? If so, you could perhaps add an argument to your function to take an `ofstream` argument and print to that?

Comment: @jswolf: It should be an `ostream&` parameter, as mentioned in my answer, so it can accept either `cout` or an `ofstream` object (or an `ostringstream`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the function does its own file I/O, it's going to be tough (that's why the "separation of concerns" software design guideline exists, it's apparently being violated here).  Overloading `operator <<` will not help, there's no return value from the function for such an operator to put anywhere.

If you can modify the function, have it accept an argument which is the `ostream` object to write to (this can default to `cout`).

If you can't modify the function, but it uses `std::cout`, you can use `cout.rdbuf(newbuffer)` to redirect `std::cout` by associating it with another destination.

If the function uses some other I/O library, you may have to use `freopen` or even `dup2` to remap `stdout` (the OS standard output file descriptor) to another destination.

And beware, any of the techniques involving redirection (i.e. `cout.rdbuf`, `freopen`, and `dup2`) will make a huge mess in any multithreaded program.  This probably doesn't apply to you as a beginning programmer, but when you start with threading you need to design your I/O functions to use whatever stream you want, global solutions just won't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I think im going to modify the function, but im not sure how to work with ostream.

void linkD::display_balance(){

```
ListNode *nodePtr;
nodePtr = head;

while (nodePtr){
    nodePtr->driver.print_balanceReport();
    cout<<endl;
nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}


void driver::print_balanceReport(){
    nBalance=balance;
    cout<<get_firstName()<<" ";
    cout<<get_lastName()<<" ";
    cout<<get_dLicense()<<" ";
    cout<<get_vLicense()<<" ";
    cout<<get_nBalance()<<" ";
    cout<<get_passed()<<" ";
    cout<<get_differance()<<" ";}
```

print from the class (driver)

so would i change the void into ostream and treat it like a function type?? also just for my knowledge can I traverse my linkedlist from the main, so that i skip the function??

Comment: I see, so open and declare the txt and pass it into the function and then read to it.